# User is not root if you access a a remote bash script using wget

Tags: bash

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
        echo "Sorry, you are not root."
        exit 1
fi

echo "You are root"

while true
do
    read -s -p "Password of root for mysql, : " pass
    echo
    read -s -p "Password (again): " cpass
    echo
    [ "$pass" = "$cpass" ] && break
    echo "Please try again"
done
```

When i run it using  `sudo wget -qO- http://server-ip/install  | sh`

Result is `Sorry you are not root`.

If I download the script and then run it, the while loop does not run. What could the problem be?

Comment: Why do you need a `| sh ` when you are already running as `sudo`. Can you try without the same?

Comment: How about `wget -qO- http://server-ip/install  | sudo sh` ? But let me tell you that [`curl | bash` or `wget -O- | bash` is risky business](https://www.google.com/search?q=curl+bash+risk). Especially when sh is running under sudo.

Comment: Which problem do you want to concentrate on?  I'd guess you are not root while doing wget to another server even if sudo is being used.  I see nothing that would stop the while loop from running-- are you getting any output when downloading and running?

Answer (score 4):

Your pipeline consists of two commands, `sudo` and `sh`. Only the command specified in the arguments to `sudo` is run with elevated privileges. (`sudo` is not a shell keyword that applies to the entire pipeline.)

Executing code retrieved from an external resource like this is *not* safe. Save the code to a file first and examine it to make sure it is the code you expect to execute before running it.

```
wget -qO- http://server-ip/install > script
less script
sudo sh script
```

Ideally, the remote server is also publishing a checksum you can use to verify `script` without having to read it manually. You still need to trust that the remote server is supplying code you actually want to run, but this way you ensure that an attacker isn't intercepting your request and supplying different code than what the remote server is sending.

Comment: And especially with people doing things like [Detecting the use of "curl | bash" server side](https://www.idontplaydarts.com/2016/04/detecting-curl-pipe-bash-server-side/) it is smart never to do this (it was never smart to do this but it is even less smart now).